# Why does my ms sql stored proc only return an integer(and how to amend it)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

Hi I am using vs2008 making an asp.net.vb app. The following stored procedure resolutely insists on returning an integer. I on the other hand was hoping for, and expecting,  a single name to be returned. Can anyone help amend the sp or describe what I need to do to get the result I desire.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getusername]
(
@email varchar ,
@retvalue nvarchar (10)output
)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON    

SELECT        myemailaddress
FROM            newtable
WHERE        (myemailaddress = @email)
```

Thanks for all and any help.

Comment: How were you calling the procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return code for a stored procedure is always an integer. You can set it by using the `Return` statement in your procedure like so:

`Return 9`

There is no way to return anything other than an integer using the procedure's return code. If you want to use your output parameter, you need to set it:

```
Select @retValue = somecolumn
From newTable
Where myemailaddress = @email
```

**ADDITION**

Here is a small test script:

```
Create Table dbo.NewTable ( MyEmailAddress varchar(30) not null Primary Key )

Insert dbo.NewTable(MyEmailAddress) Values('foo@mydomain.com')
Insert dbo.NewTable(MyEmailAddress) Values('bar@mydomain.com')
Insert dbo.NewTable(MyEmailAddress) Values('gamma@mydomain.com')
GO

Create Procedure dbo.GetUserName
    @Email varchar(30)
    , @RetValue nvarchar(10) OUTPUT
As

Set NoCount On;

Select @RetValue = Cast(MyEmailAddress As nvarchar(10))
From dbo.NewTable
Where MyEmailAddress = @Email

Return
GO

Declare @ProcValue nvarchar(10)

exec dbo.GetUserName 'foo@mydomain.com', @ProcValue OUTPUT
Select @ProcValue

exec dbo.GetUserName 'bar@mydomain.com', @ProcValue OUTPUT
Select @ProcValue
```

Perhaps you have a syntax error in your script?

Comment: I have tried that and it results in the ' must declare scalar value @retvalue ' error

Comment: @simon - I suspect you have a syntax error in your script. I have amended my response to include a test script.

Comment: thank you for taking the time and trouble to do that I shall try it out.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the integer you are talking about is actually the return value from the stored procedure and not the output parameter @retvalue.

**Update**

Looking at the SQL in your question and the code in your comment below, you are hitting this problem from two slightly different angles.

If you use cmd.ExecuteScalar it will return the the first column of the first row from your stored procedure's `SELECT` statement (looking at your stored procedure this would be `myemailaddress`). This is returned as an `object` DataType. Therefore you must change `retvalue = cmd.ExecuteScalar` to `retvalue = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar)`

If you use this technique then the declaration `@retvalue nvarchar (10)output` in your stored procedure is not needed.

To be honest, this solution is a bit ghetto, a cleaner route would be to use `output` parameters in your stored procedure and then instead of `retvalue = cmd.ExecuteScalar` use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` and then pick up the value of the `output` parameter such as `retvalue = Convert.ToString(cmd.Parameters("@retvalue").Value)`. This is what Thomas in another answer implies using his interpretation of your stored procedure.

Comment: If that's the case, and I agree with your suspicion, then how can I get the return value please?

Comment: You have to declare output parameters as part of your stored proc call, which defines what local variables will receive the values from the proc.

Comment: With cmd
                .Connection = con
                .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                .CommandText = "getusername"
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email)
                .Parameters.Add("@retvalue", retvalue, SqlDbType.NVarChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
                retvalue = cmd.ExecuteScalar ' also tried executenonquery

            End With

Comment: @simon now you have supplied some .NET code I have updated my original answer

Answer (score 0):

What we really need to see is the VB code which is calling the stored proc.  If you do a 
DataAdapter.Fill(dataset) you will get the results of the SELECT statement in the DataSet.

Sample code:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim dataAdatpter As SqlDataAdapter = Nothing       ' Nothing assignment removes warning message
Dim mustCloseConnection As Boolean = False

PrepareCommand(cmd, connection, CType(Nothing, SqlTransaction), commandType, commandText, commandParameters, mustCloseConnection)

' Create the DataAdapter & DataSet
dataAdatpter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

' Fill the DataSet using default values for DataTable names, etc
dataAdatpter.Fill(ds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have done it, I'm not sure why this works and my other efforts didn't,but thank you to all who took the time to respond. My code now looks like this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getusername]

(
@email varchar (50) ,
```

@retvalue varchar (50) output
    )

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

SELECT        myname
  FROM            newtable
  WHERE        (myemailaddress = @Email)

and the vb stuff like this

```
Dim email = value
        Dim con = New SqlConnection()
        Dim connectionString = My.Resources.textstrings.dbconnect
        con.ConnectionString = connectionString
        con.Close()
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand
        cmd = New SqlCommand()
        With cmd
            .Connection = con
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .CommandText = "getusername"
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", value)
            Dim retvalue As New SqlParameter("@retvalue", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
            retvalue.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            .Parameters.Add(retvalue)
        End With
        username = cmd.ExecuteScalar()
```

Thanks again.